# Why is slick slider setoption not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Trying to use slickSetOption to set autoplay to true, will have this trigger another way eventually.
But the problem is that when I try to use slickSetOption nothing happens. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/123autoplay123/pen/bGKmLzg)

```
  $(".slick-slider").slick({
   slidesToShow: 3,
   infinite:false,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   autoplay: false,
   autoplaySpeed: 2000
  });
  
 $(".slick-slider").slick("slickSetOption", "autoplay", true, false);
```